# Passing multiple xml objects to jax-rs service

Tags: java, android, jaxb, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using JAX-RS Jersey and JAXB on my server code to implement services, which I consume from an Android app. I already have the services returning my custom objects in xml format and I can unmarshal them just fine on the client side.
Now I want to send my custom objects from the client to the server in xml, I wrote a simple test but it fails with error 400.
This is the service:

```
@POST
@Path("/test")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
public String test(List<Client> clientList, Client client) {
    //do something with clientList and client
    return response;
}
```

This is the xml I send in the request body:

```
<clientList>
    <client name="" phone="" address="" />        
    <client name="" phone="" address="" />        
</clientList>
<client name="" phone="" address="" />
```

And here is the client code:

```
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);                
httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "text/plain");
httpPost.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(xmlFromAbove, HTTP.UTF_8));
HttpResponse response = androidHttpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

If I only put one parameter in the service it works fine, but with more than one it seems that JAXB doesn't know how to unmarshall them.
Do I have to wrap all the parameters I need in one custom object, or is there simpler way to do it?

I also tried passing the xml strings as FormParams and using the following code to unmarshal it

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Client.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();            
List<Client> clients = 
    (List<Client>)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(clientListXml));
```

But it didn't work either, it throws

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"clients").  
    Expected elements are <{}client>
```

When I return a List from the service, jaxb marshalls it correctly, without having to wrap the list in a custom object. Do I have to wrap it anyway in order to do the unmarshalling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I have to wrap all the parameters I need in one custom object,

Yes, that would be one option.

> or is there simpler way to do it?

Not simpler, but you could also use multipart media type to send a request entity consisting of several parts - look at the javadoc of the jersey-multipart module for more info (http://jersey.java.net/nonav/apidocs/latest/jersey/contribs/jersey-multipart/index.html)

> When I return a List from the service, jaxb marshalls it correctly, without having to wrap the list in a custom object.

That's because Jersey wraps it for you. If you are unmarshalling the list manually, you have to wrap it yourself.

Comment: I ended up just passing the xml strings as FormParams, and wrapping the List parameters in my own custom objects for unmarshalling. Anyway I'll take a look at jersey multipart. Thanks